# ¿Cómo desahabilitar campos de un select con librería select2 y jquery?

Tags: jquery

Como deshabilitar campos de un select, si este fue creado a partir de la librería select2, y las  del select se llenan mediante petición a API.

Tengo una duda que no he logrado resolver. Estoy trabajando en un campo de tipo select, haciendo uso de la librería select2, los valores de dicho select se obtienen mediante la petición a una API, esta API tiene una clave llamada "tipo" con base en esto se decide si mostrar o no todos los resultados del API en el select.

Por ejemplo, en mi primer iteracion a la API me muestra todos los datos que esta contenga[image: imagen de los datos de la API].
Y así es como se ven dentro del campo select
[image: imagen de los datos dentro del campo tipo select]
Estos datos se agregan a un campo tipo select, en el cual el usuario puede elegir dos o mas opciones, mi problema es que si el usuario ha elegido un tipo IMPLEMENTACION, no debería poder elegir un tipo COMBO y viceversa.
[image: imagen del select2 con los datos elegidos por el cliente]}
Alguien podría darme una idea de como resolverlo, muchas gracias. Adjunto tambien el codigo que llevo:

```
        function multipleSelect() {
        url = "{{ 
        route('get_descripcion_servicios_adicionales','clave') }}"
        const selectMultiple = 
       document.getElementById('multiple_select_implementaciones');

        axios.get(url, axiosConfig).then((value) => {
            const isPaquete = value.data.data;
            console.log(isPaquete)

            $("#multiple_select_implementaciones").change(
                function() {
                    for (let i of isPaquete) {
                        // console.log(i.tipo)
                        if (i.tipo == 'combo') {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Ya tienes un paquete individual, por lo tanto no puedes elegir un paquete combo.'
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }).multipleSelect({
                width: '100%'
            });
            let multiple = null;
            value.data.data.forEach(el => multiple +=
                `<option value="${el.tipo}" >${el.servicio}</option>`
            );
            selectMultiple.innerHTML = multiple;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y en lugar de una imagen con código, coloca el código, también lo que has intentado + investigado. Aquí una serie de recomendaciones para mejorar las preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Para servirles :D por otro lado, edita tu pregunta e incluye todo el código que sea necesario para reproducir tu escenario, caso contrario estaríamos yendo casi a ciegas. Dato adicional: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43802081/3613462 y https://stackoverflow.com/q/31261035/3613462 podrían ser de ayuda